# Parse Local Datastore: manage dirty pinned objects

Tags: javascript, android, ios, parse-platform

How can one track whose Parse Local Datastore pinned objects were changed so that only those objects are synched with the server? Is it safe/enough to label pinned objects as dirty and only synch those to the server? Or does saveEventually handles this automatically, i.e., it only synchs dirty objects to the server and therefore the labelling of those pinned objects is redundant?

Thanks!

Comment: They recently released their APIs as open source. As far as I could tell, it is safe to simply use saveeventually. You can of course pin changes to a special "changed" pin and save em all at once, if that suits you better

Answer (score 0):

Jorge,
  The simple answer is saveEventually will handle saving the changed object to the local datastore and will also save to the Parse server as well when a connection becomes available.

**Here is what the Parse Android guide has to say:**
The advantage is that if the user currently doesn't have a network connection, saveEventually will store the update on the device until a network connection is re-established. If your app is closed before the connection is back, Parse will try again the next time the app is opened.

**Parse Android Guide:**
https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#localdatastore
(Scroll down to the section labeled Saving Objects Offline)